# How to insert object value into a formula?

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script

In my code I store a list of names in an array called data.  So later I can recall these names in a loop by giving reference such as data[1] to get the first name.

The below line of code WORKS fine

```
cell.setFormula("=query('Open Details'!$A$1:$Z$231,\"SELECT A WHERE V contains 'John Doe'\",0)");
```

Let's assume data[1] resolves to the name John Doe.  How do I use data[1] in the above formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cell.setFormula("=query('Open Details'!$A$1:$Z$231,\"SELECT A WHERE V contains '" + data[1] + "'\",0)");
```

You could also place the names in a second sheet or a different column in the same sheet in the file and reference each cell in each instance of the formula:

```
cell.setFormula("=query('Open Details'!$A$1:$Z$231,\"SELECT A WHERE V contains Names!$A$1\",0)");
```

Comment: The first one worked! For the second one, though I understand it conceptually, I don't know if I will be able to change the reference "Names!$A$1" to "Names!$A$2" in a loop using loop counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the backwards tick to create a template literal and insert the variable into the string.

Template literals can be used to represent multi-line strings and then use "interpolation" to insert variables as seen below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
var data = ['Jane Doe', 'John Doe'];

var query = `=query('Open Details'!$A$1:$Z$231,\'SELECT A WHERE V contains '${data[1]}'\'',0)`;

console.log(query);
```